# Spring boot: Use same services for a rest api and for local execution

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, crud

I have developed a basic CRUD using spring boot and it is working correctly. My main codes are the following:

**Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController  
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")  
@RequestMapping(value="/api")  
public class Controller {

    @Autowired  
    private PruebaService pruebaservice;  
      
    @PostMapping("save-prueba")
    public ResponseEntity<?> savePrueba(@RequestBody PruebaDTO pruebaDTO) {
        Prueba prueba = new Prueba(pruebaDTO.getColumna());
        pruebaservice.savePrueba(prueba);
        return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("Guardado correctamente"), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
      
    //Other methods for the CRUD
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PruebaService {

    @Autowired  
    private PruebaRepository pruebadao;  

    public Prueba savePrueba(Prueba prueba) {
        if (prueba != null)
            return pruebaRepository.save(prueba); 
        return new Prueba();
    }

    //Other methods for the CRUD
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface PruebaRepository extends JpaRepository<Prueba, Integer> {  
    
    Void save(Optional<Prueba> PruebaToUpdate); 
    
}
```

This CRUD is working correctly when I used it from the web application, but my problem is when I try to use the code from a main class (local).

So I have the following code that it is not working:

**Main:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PruebaService pruebaService = new PruebaService();
        Prueba prueba = new Prueba("prueba");
        pruebaService.savePrueba(prueba);
    }
```

This does not work because it returns a null pointer exception because pruebaRepository is not initialiced in pruebaService, so the questions are:

1. How is possible that the repository class is inicialited if I use a http request (by the controller class) but it is not when I use a "local" way?
2. How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: What you are doing in your `main` method is outside Spring context that's why you get the null pointer exception. You have developed a Spring Application, you cannot use classes/services that expect to live in a Spring context, "standalone", why would you want it anyway?

Comment: You need to load manually the Spring context in your main method, likely you will want to have a different context than the webapp but reusing only some services (and not the http stack for instance)

Comment: @pleft, I have the web application developed in Angular, and I am trying to do this because I am developing a batch process to load some information in the database but it will be executed only maybe once and in any case I dont need to call this process from the web, so I thought this would be the best option but I am open to listen which will be the most standart way.

Comment: @GaëlJ, how can I load the spring context? do you have some example or link where I can see this?

Comment: You can have a look to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-application-context. As I said, it will probably be better to create a dedicated context for your batch app with only necessary beans: don't load everything.

Comment: I am trying to follow this example using the "Java-Based Configuration" and the "AnnotationConfigApplicationContext" but I cannot get it. I have change "account" by "prueba" but in the link I think that the repository is a class and in my case is an interface, so there should be some different that I dont know how to resolve it...